# How to add delay to while loop

Tags: java

I have a while loop and what I want it to do is every 1 second count up an integer up to 10.
The code that I have now simply spits out 1-10 as quick as it possibly can with no delay, I'm un-sure how to add a delay.
      package apackage;

```
public class loops {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int countdown = 1;
        while (countdown < 10) {
            System.out.println(countdown);
            ++countdown;
        }
    }
}
```

So, thanks for reading and appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Look at [`Thread#sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
public class loops {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        int countdown = 1;
        while (countdown < 10){
            System.out.println(countdown);
            ++countdown;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Soon enough someone here will tell you that it's not accurate enough due to the additional time spent on the countdown itself at every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider Thread.sleep()

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) is the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

**Add this at the beginning of the loop:**

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

**And add this at the end of the loop:**

```
long wait = time + 1000 - System.currentTimeMillis();
if (wait > 0)
    Thread.sleep(wait);
```